# Why do we need parentheses around block macro?

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel

In linux, `container_of` macro is enclosed in seemingly "extra" parentheses:

```
 #define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
                const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); 
                (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Instead of it, can we just use

```
 #define container_of(ptr, type, member) { \
                const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); 
                (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );}
```

?

Are the parentheses mandatory or are they just for precaution?

Comment: This should be tagged GCC rather than C.......

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's necessary. One of the "tricks" used is GCC's [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) that require this 'strange' `({ code })` syntax.

Code that uses this macro wouldn't compile without that in most use cases (and it's not valid C).

See also:
[Rationale behind the container_of macro in linux/list.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083734/rationale-behind-the-container-of-macro-in-linux-list-h)

And: [container_of](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html) by Greg Kroah-Hartman.

Answer (score 9):

`({...})` is a braced group, a code block that can be used inside an expression. The last statement determines its value.

Inside macros you use it to let macros behave the same way as functions.
Mostly a `static inline` function would be preferable.

Related questions:

- [Are compound statements (blocks) surrounded by parens expressions in ANSI C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238016/are-compund-statements-blocks-surrounded-by-parens-expressions-in-ansi-c)
- [ISO C equivalent of braced-groups within expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626397/iso-c-equivalent-of-braced-groups-within-expressions)